# How do I read in MATLAB a text file of doubles with variable number of columns per line?

Tags: matlab, csv, file-io, text-files

My file looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6
7 8 9
...
```

I'm looking for a MATLAB one-liner (or two) that can turn this into:

```
C{1} = [1 2 3 4]
C{2} = [5 6]
C{3} = [7 8 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner, broken into several lines for readability

```
C = cellfun(@(x) sscanf(x, '%f').', ...
        regexp(...
            regexprep(...
                fileread('test.txt'), ...
                '(\r|\n$)', ''), ...
            '\n', 'split'), ...
        'uni', 0).';
```